# How to add comma separator to Venn diagram

Tags: r, venn-diagram

In r is there a way to add the comma separator to thousands on a Venn diagram.

```
venn.plot <- VennDiagram::draw.pairwise.venn(10000, 7000, 3000, c("First", "Second"), scaled = FALSE)

grid::grid.draw(venn.plot)
```

The resulting chart looks like the one below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like this function was designed to do that. If you really want to use this function, you could "hack" it to replace the default formatting code it uses for labels. Note that this method is very fragile since we are editing particular "lines" of code. First make a copy of the function

```
myvenn <- VennDiagram::draw.pairwise.venn
```

Here's the default formatter

```
body(myvenn)[[46]]
# wrapLab <- function(num) {
#     stri = ""
#     if (print.mode[1] == "percent") {
#         stri <- paste(signif(num * 100/denom, digits = sigdigs), 
#             "%", sep = "")
#         if (isTRUE(print.mode[2] == "raw")) {
#             stri <- paste(stri, "\n(", num, ")", sep = "")
#         }
#     }
#     if (print.mode[1] == "raw") {
#         stri <- num
#         if (isTRUE(print.mode[2] == "percent")) {
#             stri <- paste(stri, "\n(", paste(signif(num * 100/denom, 
#                 digits = sigdigs), "%)", sep = ""), sep = "")
#         }
#     }
#     return(stri)
# }
```

Let's replace that with a call to `prettyNum` to add the commas

```
body(myvenn)[[46]][[3]] <- quote(function(x) {
    prettyNum(x ,big.mark=",",scientific=FALSE)
})
```

Now we can call our version of the function

```
venn.plot <- myvenn(10000, 7000, 3000, c("First", "Second"), scaled = FALSE)
grid::grid.draw(venn.plot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could also edit the items manually.

```
venn.plot[[5]][["label"]] <- "7,000"
venn.plot[[6]][["label"]] <- "4,000"
venn.plot[[7]][["label"]] <- "3,000"

grid::grid.draw(venn.plot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way with a loop

```
venn.plot <- VennDiagram::draw.pairwise.venn(10000, 7000, 3000, c("First", "Second"), scaled = FALSE)

for(i in 1:length(venn.plot)){

 if(!is.null(venn.plot[[i]][["label"]]) &&
    !is.na(as.numeric(venn.plot[[i]][["label"]]))
 ) {

    venn.plot[[i]][["label"]] <- prettyNum(venn.plot[[i]][["label"]], big.mark = ",")

 }
 }

Warning messages:
1: NAs introduced by coercion 
2: NAs introduced by coercion 
grid::grid.draw(venn.plot)
```